# Elastic Beanstalk - Configure the load balancer to redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I've been struggling and googling this issue for a while and although it seems to 
me like a pretty standard requirement I couldn't find a working solution anywhere.

I don't want to disable HTTP, only redirect it to HTTPS.
Not between the load balancer and the EC2 instances, but between the browser and the load balancer.

I have created an `Elastic Beanstalk environment (Linux)` for my `Spring Boot` app, 
configured the load balancer for HTTP + HTTPS using the management console and
configured environment variables and IP tables using `.config` files in an `.ebextensions`
folder zipped with the app's JAR file.

Then I tried adding an `NGINX` configuration for a permanent HTTP to HTTPS 
redirect using a config file with a "files" key, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your Nginex configuration file

Answer (score 0):

This is my NGINX configuration to redirect to https:

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Give it a try if not please paste your NGINX configuration file

Comment: This is identical to my configuration. But instead of configuring NGINX on each and every EC2 instance what I'm trying to do is to add a configuration file to my .ebextensions folder and apply this configuration automatically using a "files" option. Some like (not sure what SOME_PATH should be):  
  `files:  
    "<SOME_PATH>/000_http_to_https.conf":  
    mode: "000755"  
    owner: root  
    owner: root  
    content: |  
      listen 80;  
      listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;  
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`